# How to align inline formatted text with react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have a text with some basic formatting, bold, italic and so on. How is this done properly with react native?

By default, the `<Text>` elements break. If I use `flex` they align more or less right, but not if the normal text before and after the formatted text is too long.

Example code:

```
<View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
    <Text>Normal text normal text normal text norm</Text>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}> bold text</Text>
    <Text> normal text normal text normal text normal text</Text>
</View>
```

Result:

[image: incorrect formatting]

The only workaround I found is to split the text in words and put each word in a separate `<Text>`. But this can't be the correct solution... I hope?

```
<View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
    {"Normal text normal text normal text norm".split(" ").map((word) => <Text>{word} </Text>)}
    {"bold text".split(" ").map((word) => <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{word} </Text>)}
    {"normal text normal text normal text normal text".split(" ").map((word) => <Text>{word} </Text>)}
</View>
```

Result:

[image: correct formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example [in the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/Text) - you can nest Text elements inside other Text elements to get the behavior you're looking for. Nested Text will inherit styles from parent Text, and you can add your desired styles on top of that.

```js
<View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
  <Text>
    Normal text normal text normal text norm
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}> bold text</Text>
    normal text normal text normal text normal text
  </Text>
</View>
```